# Alfresco Share - Dynamic rendering of fields in a form

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

My question is more or less in the title, I added a new data type in my data model.

```
<type name="moi:montype">
  <title>titre type</title>
  <parent>cm:content</parent>
  <mandatory-aspects>
    <aspect>moi:monaspect</aspect>
  </mandatory-aspects>
</type>
```

This one uses a new aspect in which I added a new field

```
<aspect name="moi:monaspect">
  <title>titre aspect</title>
  <properties>
    <property name="moi:monchamp">
      <type>d:text</type>
      <mandatory>false</mandatory>
    </property>
    ...
  </properties>
</aspect>
```

I then displayed this new field in a Share form by editing the file share-config-custom.xml.

```
<config evaluator="node-type" condition="moi:montype">
  <forms>
    <form>
      <field-visibility>
        <show id="moi:monchamp"/>
        ...
      </field-visibility>
      <appearance>
        <field id="moi:monchamp" label="Champ texte" />
        ...
      </appearance>
    </form>
  </forms>
</config>
```

Till then, I could test my changes and the new field displays well.
But I would like to go further, and condition for example the display of the field depending on the logged in user's group.
If the logged in user is part of the "priviledged group", then the field is displayed, otherwise it will not, or only in read only mode.

Do you think we can do this ? And how ?
I looked at documentation, but can't find my happiness.
I don't ask for the full solution, but for tips to follow.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Every field has a component renderer. These are implemented using FreeMarker. Most of the time, as in your case, you are relying on the default component renderer. In addition to the options mentioned by Matjaz, another option would be to point the field at a custom renderer. The renderer could inspect the user's group membership and the group required for this field (maybe passed in as an argument, for example), and then decide whether or not to show itself.

Comment: Thank you for this input.
I though the only way to query the repository was via a .js file, not via .ftl.

Comment: Yes, but your FTL can always add client-side JavaScript which can query the repository.

Comment: How do you tell there is JavaScript in FTL ?
I tried adding this within textfield.ftl, but I got error 500.

${person.properties.userName}

Should I add a <script> tag or something like that ?

Comment: Yes, you can add a script tag. But simply adding a script tag won't give you access to javascript objects like that. The topic is too involved to encapsulate in a comment, but basically you write a client-side JavaScript component (there are many examples of this in Alfresco Share) and then instantiate that component from within a script tag in your FTL. Then, when the browser renders the page, your client-side JavaScript component can use AJAX to invoke web script calls on the repository to get the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this.

The easiest way is to make a webscript which returns html for a form field based on if a current logged in user is in your target group. Then add a form control which is only javascript making an ajax call to the webscript and and appending results to your container div which is specified in your form control (ftl).

The second approach you could use is to extend "org.alfresco.repo.forms.processor.AbstractFilter" and implement the functionality in Java. You could probably implement after generate and remove the form field if current logged in user is not in a target group.

Hope this helps a bit... :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this as alfresco does not allow you to set rights on node properties.

Every field has control template, you could define your own. in your template you would define   how this property is rendered depending of user type.

```
<config evaluator="node-type" condition="cm:content">
   <forms>
      <form>
         <appearance>
            <field id="cm:title">
               <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/yourOwnFtl.ftl" />
            </field>
         </appearance>
      </form>
   </forms>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to write your own share config form evaluator (like node-type ...)

This could check for node type and user permission role/group

let you write one config for each setup (per user group/role)

...

NB! this will one work for forms, so is purely a cosmetical setup, alfresco interface and CIFS etc. will not support this setup.